# Pass Set<UITouch> from a Gesture delegate

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to do this part something like,

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {

        SomeClass.handleTouchEvents(touch, event: nil)

        return true

    }
```

In Some Class,

```
func handleTouchEvents(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, event: UIEvent?)
```

This `Set<UITouch>` I want to know how to construct and pass it from a UIGesturesDelegate touch object.

I need it as `Set<UITouch>` because there are some dependencies on that.

I tried like this,

```
let touchEvent:Set<UITouch> = [touch]
SomeClass.handleTouchEvents(touchEvent, event: nil)
```

But it crashes

Comment: Use the initializer of `Set`, e.g.: `Set(touch)`.

Comment: Show the details of the crash. Where does it crash, what's the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
let touches = Set([touch])
SomeClass.handleTouchEvents(touches, event: nil)
```